# Pandas replace NaN value by string under conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I am trying to do is to replace the NaN value by a string 'school'. If longitude is within the range of 114.8 to 115.2 and latitude is within the range of 19.8 to 20.2, the NaN value in the location column with be replaced by the string 'School'.

```
df=
    Date            Longitude Latitude   Location
0   2020-01-01 01:00    115.1   20.0         NaN 
1   2020-01-01 01:01    115.0   20.1         NaN
2   2020-01-01 01:02    114.9   19.9         NaN
3   2020-01-01 01:03    123.1   20.0         NaN
4   2020-01-01 01:04    115.0   18.9         NaN
```

I would like to convert my DataFrame as follows

```
df=
    Date            Longitude Latitude   Location
0   2020-01-01 01:00    115.1   20.0      school
1   2020-01-01 01:01    115.0   20.1      school
2   2020-01-01 01:02    114.9   19.9      school
3   2020-01-01 01:03    123.1   20.0       NaN
4   2020-01-01 01:04    115.0   18.9       NaN
```

What I have tried to do is

```
df.loc[((df['Longitude']<115.2) & (df['Longitude']>114.8) & (df['Latitude']>19.8) & (df['Latitude']<20.2)), df['Location']]='School'
```

However, I get an error

```
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=7441)] are in the [columns]"
```

I am not sure why this is happening and thx a lot for reading my question!

Answer (score 2):

You are close:

```
df.loc[((df['Longitude']<115.2) & (df['Longitude']>114.8) 
         & (df['Latitude']>19.8) & (df['Latitude']<20.2)), 
      'Location']='School'
```

Also, you can use `between`:

```
df.loc[((df['Longitude'].between(114.8, 115.2, inclusive=False) 
         & (df['Latitude'].between(19.8, 20.2, inclusive=False)), 
      'Location']='School'
```

Comment: Thx for your help! Works for me

Answer (score 1):

After the condition in `df.loc[]` a column name is expected as key and you are passing the series `df['Location']` which ends up giving you the key error.

mention only the column name i.e. `'Location'` and it will work.

```
df.loc[((df['Longitude']<115.2) & (df['Longitude']>114.8) & 
      (df['Latitude']>19.8) & (df['Latitude']<20.2)), 
      'Location'] = 'School'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using just numpy where method:

```
df['location'] = np.where((df['Longitude'].between(114.8, 115.2)) & ((df['Latitude'].between(19.8, 20.2)), "school", np.nan)
```